# How to remove attribute in webbrowser element

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, browser

I am using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express.
I need to remove "disabled" attribute from this element in webbrowser.

```
<input id="RegisterBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" disabled="false" name="" value="Register"></input>
```

It must look like this:

```
<input id="RegisterBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="" value="Register"></input>
```

I tried to change value of "disabled" to "" but registration doesn't work.
How can I do it?
Thanks.